# how to perform JSON.stringify on objects with ciruclar reference?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I would like to store a formgroup object in database. I am not able to stringify this object because of circular dependency. Is there a workaround for this in angular?

> form ={
> coursename: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
> content: new FormControl('',Validators.required),   }

Comment: are there any point storing `new FormControl` in db?

Comment: Apply the JSON.stringify to the "value" of the form: `const data=JSON.stringify(this.form.value)` not to the form

Answer (score 0):

```
// your code
const form = {
  coursename: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
  content: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
};

// since new FormControl() create an object with circular reference,
// so instead of taking the FormControl object, we can use FormControl.value
// which return the actual data object with no circular reference

// updated code
courseNameControl = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
contentControl = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
const form = {
  coursename: courseNameControl.value,
  content: contentControl.value,
}

// now you can stringify the form
const stringifyForm = JSON.stringify(form);
```

Comment: the form created in this way has errors:null whereas the orginal form has errors:{required:true}.

Comment: please share screenshot of component code...